# Can one use the "it" command outside of a loop in Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, syntactic-sugar

I know that in a Lisp loop, one can use the special variable "it", as in this example from Gigamonkeys:

```
(loop for key in some-list when (gethash key some-hash) collect it)
```

I was wondering if there was any equivalent concept outside of a loop besides using let to store it explicitly, something like this:

```
(let ((result (foo input)))
     (when result (push result acc)))
```

I can use let, but I was just curious as to whether there was some syntactic sugar that can make my code a little more concise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The lisp-y answer is, who cares if there isn't syntax, just add your own.

```
(defmacro awhen (test &body body)
    `(let ((it ,test))
          (when it ,@body)))
```

and then use it

```
(awhen (expensive-computation)
       (format t "~a~%" it))
```

This class of macros are often prefixed with an "a" for anaphoric. See `aif` for Paul Graham's examples in On Lisp.

Comment: Thanks! Completely forgot about that little nicety of lisp.

Comment: See? Macros are so smooth you can actually forget they exist even while you use one of them, such as `loop`.

Comment: There is also a package with many anaphoric versions of the normal control structures. It is called Anaphora. See: http://common-lisp.net/project/anaphora/